# Dependency Issue During NPM Install

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, react-redux, npm-install

I'm having an issue understanding how sepcify a valid version for `react` that satisfies it's peer (`react-native` and `react-redux`) dependencies. Here's my `package.json`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^15.3.2",
  "react-native": "0.35.0"
  "react-redux": "4.4.5",
  "redux": "3.6.0",
}
```

Initial dev work on this project (~ 2 months ago) had no issues during `npm install`, but cloning this repo into a fresh environment and running `npm install` produces the following issues:

```
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency react@~15.3.1 included from react-native will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.

npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react@15.4.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-native@0.35.0 wants react@~15.3.1
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-redux@4.4.5 wants react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0
```

It seems to be trying to install `react@15.4.2`, which is the latest version as of Mar. 20, 2017, and is correct as far as I understand the `^` semver specification.

I've tried specifying the version `15.3.1`, `15.3.2`, `^15.3.1`, `^15.3.2`, `~15.3.1`, etc etc, but no matter what I enter, the issues persist.

Also looked at the file on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.35-stable/package.json:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "~15.3.1"
},
```

and on https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/4.x/package.json:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^15.4.0-0",
  "redux": "^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0"
},
```

I'm relatively new to `package.json` files like this, and hopefully this is a simple solution, but everything I've tried is coming up empty.

Comment: Oh, also, maybe consider updating your node and npm versions, those are rather old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-native@0.35.0 needs a react version of 15.3.x, it is not compatible with react 15.4.

Changing `"react": "^15.3.2"` to `"react": "~15.3.2"` in your dependencies and doing a fresh `npm install` should solve your problem.

Comment: I'll double check this again, as in my question: "I've tried specifying the version 15.3.1, 15.3.2, ^15.3.1, ^15.3.2, ~15.3.1, etc etc" (included 15.3.2 I think)

Comment: Welp, seems that was the one I needed to solve this dependency issue. Opens up another issue with `react-native-router-flux` requiring `"react": "^15.4.2"`, but this solved the immediate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth a shot to try to re-install these dependencies, and hope that the current version installed for everything matches up.

In other words, remove those lines from your package.json, remove your modules with `rm -rf node_modules`, and then go `npm i --save react react-native redux react-redux`.

Alternatively, checkout https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app and create a new app and compare the package.json with yours.